passing arguments in to workflow_variables using map2
Im trying to setup a number of vaiable combinations for modling with tidymodels::workflow_set
I have setup a nested tibble with each combination of variables in a c() but i am unabel to pass that variable in to the work flow using map2.
i think what i am trying to do might be impossible.
variables = map2(outc,pred, \(y,x) workflow_variables(outcomes = y, predictors = x)) this line is the problem.
in all 200 permuatations the outcome is listed as y and predictor as x. not the values held in cutc and pred
combinations <- expand_grid(  
  outc = c("measurement","Ln_measurement"),
  truth = c("callibrated_true","Ln_true","true_sqr","true_cub"),
  moisture = c("","Moisture_percent","Ln_Moisture","Moisture_sqr","Moisture_cub"),
  organic = c("","SOM_percent","Ln_SOM","SOM_sqr","SOM_cub")
  )%>%
  tibble()%>%
  mutate(
    name = paste(outc,truth, moisture, organic, sep = "_"),
    pred = pmap(list(truth, moisture, organic), c),
    variables = map2(outc,pred, \(y,x) workflow_variables(outcomes = y, predictors = x))
    )


The docs for workflow_variables() note the arguments use tidyselect (same as  what dplyr uses for select()). The code you have uses character strings, so it's not working.
You could convert those to symbols or, better yet, use a dplyr selector function like all_of():
library(workflows)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

combinations <- 
  crossing(  
    outc = c("measurement", "Ln_measurement"),
    truth = c("callibrated_true", "Ln_true", "true_sqr", "true_cub"),
    moisture = c("Moisture_percent", "Ln_Moisture", "Moisture_sqr", "Moisture_cub"),
    organic = c("SOM_percent", "Ln_SOM", "SOM_sqr", "SOM_cub")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    name = paste(outc, truth, moisture, organic, sep = "_"),
    pred = pmap(list(truth, moisture, organic), c),
    variables = map2(
      outc,
      pred,
      \(y, x) workflow_variables(
        outcomes = dplyr::all_of(y),
        predictors = dplyr::all_of(x)
      )
    )
  )

combinations$variables[[1]]
#> $outcomes
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^dplyr::all_of(y)
#> env:  0x107df3b58
#> 
#> $predictors
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^dplyr::all_of(x)
#> env:  0x107df3b58
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "workflow_variables"

# test it: 

example <-
  tibble(
    callibrated_true = 1,
    Ln_Moisture = 2,
    Ln_SOM = 3,
    bogus_column = 4
  )

combinations$pred[[1]]
#> [1] "callibrated_true" "Ln_Moisture"      "Ln_SOM"
dplyr::select(example, !!combinations$variables[[1]]$predictors)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   callibrated_true Ln_Moisture Ln_SOM
#>              <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1                1           2      3

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.0.2
